# Delete similar values in dictionary of 2dlists

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have the following dictionary with 2dlist as values:

```
dictionary = {Hello: [[2001,45], [2003, 52], [2001, 6], [2002, 90]],

             Jello: [[2009,3], [2003, 4], [2009, 17], [2009,1], [2009,1],[2002, 11]],

             Cello: [[2001,5], [2001, 2], [2001, 6], [2001, 3]]}
```

I want to change the dictionary so all lists with the same year within the key have their values added up.

So each year should only show up once per key.

Making the dictionary look like this:

```
dictionary = {Hello: [[2001,51], [2003, 52], [2002, 90]],

             Jello: [[2009,22], [2003, 4], [2002, 11]],

             Cello: [[2001,16]]}
```

How would I do this? Please help.

Comment: _How would I do this? Please help._ Is there a *specific* issue? Please see [ask], [help/on-topic].

Comment: Please repeat [on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) from the
[intro tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).  
"Show me how to solve this coding problem?" is off-topic for Stack Overflow.
You have to make an honest attempt at the solution, and then ask a *specific* question about your implementation.
Stack Overflow is not intended to replace existing tutorials and documentation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are on the right track, one easy to implement solution could be to just create a `merge_years` function and use that within a **[dict_comprehension](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0274/)**:

```
def pretty_print_simple_dict(d):
    print("{")
    for key, value in d.items():
        print(f"\t{key}: {value}")
    print("}")

def merge_years(lst):
    year_counts = {}
    for year, count in lst:
        year_counts[year] = year_counts.get(year, 0) + count
    return [[year, total] for year, total in year_counts.items()]

d = {
    'Hello': [[2001, 45], [2003, 52], [2001, 6], [2002, 90]],
    'Jello': [[2009, 3], [2003, 4], [2009, 17], [2009, 1], [2009, 1],
              [2002, 11]],
    'Cello': [[2001, 5], [2001, 2], [2001, 6], [2001, 3]]
}

d = {k: merge_years(v) for k, v in d.items()}
pretty_print_simple_dict(d)
```

**Output:**

```
{
    Hello: [[2001, 51], [2003, 52], [2002, 90]]
    Jello: [[2009, 22], [2003, 4], [2002, 11]]
    Cello: [[2001, 16]]
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot bro. Is there anyway you could think of doing this without importing libraries?

Comment: @unknownjumper There you go :)